# get data from Arraylist with index 0

Tags: android, arrays, indexing

I would like to get first data inside Arraylist but my code getting issue that String img contain null data. here is my code :

```
private List<String> imagedUploaded = new ArrayList<>();
....
private void uploadImageFile(List<Uri> imgUrl) {
    for (Uri uri : imgUrl) {
        StorageReference fileToUpload = storageRef.child(productID).child(getFileName(uri));
        fileToUpload.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                listImageSelectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                imagedUploaded.add(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString()); // get image downloadurl
                **defImg = imagedUploaded.get(0);**
                productImage = product_Ref.child("product_image").child(productID);
                productImage.setValue(imagedUploaded);
                selectedImages.clear();

            }

        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Upload Image Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

here when i want to call index result

```
uploadProduct() {
    product = product_Ref.child(path1).child(path2).child(path3).child(productID);
    DataUploadProduct data = new DataUploadProduct();

    data.setName(etProductName.getText().toString());
    data.setPrice(etPrice.getText().toString());

    **data.setDef_image(defImg);**
    data.setWeight(etWeight.getText().toString());
    data.setDescription(etDescription.getText().toString());
    product.setValue(data);
}
```

in this case imagedUploaded contain :

```
0 = http://www.url.com1
1 = http://www.url.com2
2 = http://www.url.com3
3 = http://www.url.com4
```

i want to get data only index 0, how i can do that?

Comment: You said there is an issue with your code, what is the issue exactly?

Comment: i got String img with null data

Comment: `taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString()` is returning null in every case.

Comment: no, there is data like above

Comment: Are you sure? Can you `Log` or `Toast` the value to see that it's not null

Comment: that code is work properly, that code is to get url from image in firebase, just assume that the variable is there data as above.

Comment: Can you share more code so that flow of code can be understood? I m sure something is wrong with your code flow.

Comment: yes, and also the place where you use your `img` string

Comment: please check updated  above...

Comment: Your `defImg` is getting `null` somewhere before using it.

Comment: i set defimg as global variable

Comment: what is your `selectedImages` ?